# Advanced CSS grid customization

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a grid where column adjust itself depending upon item width and then move to next line if necessary. I have tried `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr);` but it is not working in my case. The columns are overlapping each other as shown in picture.[image]

I have created a demo on [codepen](https://codepen.io/amit78523/pen/XWVbmjP). Everything that is expected from the code is explained in it.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.grid>div {
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  height: fit-content;
}

.grid>div>video {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <!--     <div>
      The number of inner div here can be dynamic.
      Sometimes 1 or 2 or more.
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div> -->
    <video src="" width=320 height=270></video>
    <video src="" width=320 height=270></video>
    <video src="" width=320 height=270></video>
  </div>
  <div>
    <!--     <div>
      The number of these outer div can also be dynamic.
      Expectation: As it has only 1 inner div, it should adjust in remaining space on right. But if there were two or more inner div (depending upon width and remaining space) it would move to next line.
    </div> -->
    <video src="" width=320 height=270></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If in minmax `100px` is greater than what `1fr` would be, the browser replaces the whole `minmax` expression by `100px` fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to have 2 layers of `grid` for your case, and `min-width` of your videos will be recognised by `grid`

Here is [the sandbox](https://jsfiddle.net/j4so73eb/2/)

Full SCSS modification

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit, minmax(340px, 1fr));
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100vw;
  & > div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit, minmax(340px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 8px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    & > video {
      border:1px dashed red;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually those inner div are video element in my original code. So this will not work as video width will change to accommodate n number of videos in that outer div.

Comment: Could you simulate it in your sandbox too? By the way, you also can try to set `width: 100%;` or your video `width: 100%;` that may help @AmitKumar

Comment: I have updated my codepen with video elements instead of div.

Comment: You can try this https://jsfiddle.net/j4so73eb/2/ instead, @AmitKumar. By the way, I updated my answer too